# Use of prepositions in time period expressions: "from 1 to 6 December" or simply "1 to 6 December"?

Tags: prepositions, periods

Is it correct to say "from 1 to 6 December"?
Or we need to use just "1 to 6 December"?

For example like in this sentence,

> This subscription is available only from 1 to 6 December.

Comment: It would be better if you provide some examples showing how you're going to use it in your sentences.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I've added example

Comment: "This subscription is only available from 1st - 6th December." A hyphen between times or dates tells us that something starts from one and lasts until the other.

Comment: In writing to show that you use ordinals and not cardinals, add the postfix to the number: 1st, 6th.  Otherwise, use words (especially for one-digit numbers).  Also, if those are ordinals, you need "of" before the month name.

Comment: Time period expressions are also very variable between dialect variations of English.

Comment: Thank you, guys! But what if I need to use some period in more common way. Like "The exhibition [or whatever] will be opened from 10th June to 25th August"

Comment: In the US it would be "...from June 10th to August 25th"

Answer (score 1):

The two expressions have two different implications.

> The subscription is available only from 1 to 6 December

This implies that there is an offer that one can only take advantage of during a certain period. That is, the subscription can only be bought from 1 December to 6 December.

> The subscription is available only 1 to 6 December

This carries the implication, at least in my mind, of something that lasts only a few days.

If you want to make that implication clear, you can say that the subscription *lasts* from 1 December to 6 December.